# Ionic Appflow: Live update with free plan

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-appflow

I want to try the Ionic Appflow for my Android app, I see that I have 100 live update monthly.

I successfuly link my app to the ionic git and commit/push my code.
I installed the Appflow SDK too in my app.

Actually, I want to try the live update but apparently I need a build for that and the build require the premium plan…

What is the way to do that so ?

Thank you in advance

Sébastien